# How print call work on my newly created Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying to learn how classes work on Python and new to this, I have the following class defined as 'Animal':

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, size, color, mood):
    # init: consists of statements that bind the parameters passed to init to the instance o f the class, when an instance
    # is created.
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.mood = mood
        self.alive = True

    def feeling(self):
        # first method, methods are limited to the class, that is why their name does not need to be unique.
        return "The", self.color, str(self), " is feeling", self.mood, "."

    def colors(self, other):
        return "The", str(self), "is", self.color, "and the", str(other), "is", other.color, "."
```

I then create an instance of the Animal object as follow:

```
hippo = Animal("large", "purple", 'amused')
```

Finally I call a method on my object as follow:

```
print(hippo.feeling())
```

My expectation is to get an output like below:

```
"The purple hippo is feeling amused."
```

But what I get in output if I print the same argument as above is:

```
('The', 'purple', '<__main__.Animal object at 0x7f43cc978160>', ' is feeling', 'amused', '.')
```

Can someone explain please why the output is similar to a list? also why str(self) returned the object name rather than the word hippo.

The original code in the tutorial was written in Python 3.5, I thought that may have caused it, but I tried the online IDE on https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online/ for Python 3.5.1 and the result was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the animal name when you initialize it — the class won't know the variable name.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size, color, mood):
    # init: consists of statements that bind the parameters passed to init to the instance of the class, when an instance
    # is created. 

    # pass the name to the class
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.mood = mood
        self.alive = True

    def feeling(self):
    # first method, methods are limited to the class, that is why their name does not need to be unique.
        return str("The " + self.color + " " + self.name + " is feeling " + self.mood + ".")

    def colors(self, other):
        return str("The ", self.name, " is " + self.color + " and the " + other.name, " is ", other.color, ".")
```

The output:

```
hippo = Animal("hippo", "large", "purple", 'amused')
print(hippo.feeling())
# The purple hippo is feeling amused.
```

Comment: I think this is what OP needs.+1

Comment: Would have been better with string formatting instead of string concatenation though...

Answer (score 0):

Your method uses commas to separate arguments. Use an f-string, and print instead of returning, as such:

```
print(f”The {self.size} {self.color} Animal is feeling {self.mood}.”)
```

Also, you expect `self` to somehow return the name of the variable. Instead, pass the animal type to the function in **init**.

Comment: It's worth to mention `f-strings` are introduced from python3.6 Since OP is using python3.5 He can always use `format`

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @ Ch3steR, you can use `__repr__` or `__str__`. Both serve for the purpose. example is as below:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Test()"
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "member of Test"
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t
Test()
>>> print(t)
member of Test
```

Comment: When I commented I misread the question. OP needs to get the only the class name

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to address here

1. The value return from the `def feeling(self)` function is a tuple, whenever the return values are seprated by a comma, the function returns a tuple consiting of all the return values. Hence we you try to print it it comes looking like a list. So either return a string or modify how you are printing the returned values from the tuple.
2. You want to get the instance name of class object when you are printing it. i.e
   `hippo = Animal("large", "purple", 'amused')` for this you expect str(self) to return the instance name, which is a bit non trivial. First define this funtion `def __str__(self):` to get desired output whenever you use `str(self)`. Second to get the variable name either supply the name as a class variable in constructor and use it, which would be easier way or you can use `python-varname` package to use the `varname()` function to acheive this.

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = varname()


k = Klass()
# k.id == 'k'
```

Answer (score 0):

Expandable using list comprehension,

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, size, color, mood):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.mood = mood
        self.alive = True 

    def feeling(self):
    # first method, methods are limited to the class, that is why their name does not need to be unique.
        return str(f"The {self.color} {self. name} is feeling {self.mood}.")


    def colors(self, other):
        return str(f"The {self.name} is {self.color}  and the {other.name} is {other.color}.")


n = int(input("No of Animals:"))
Animals = []
for i in range(n):
    print(f"Enter Details for Animal No.{i+1}")
    s = Animal(*[input(f'Enter {info}: ')for info in ["Name", "Size", "Color", "Mood"]])
    Animals.append(s)

for i in range(len(Animals)):
    print(f"\nAnimal {i+1}")
    print(Animals[i].feeling())
```

```
No of Animals:1
Enter Details for Animal No.1
Enter Name: Hippo
Enter Size: large
Enter Color: purple
Enter Mood: happy

Animal 1
The purple Hippo is feeling happy.

[Program finished]
```